# Oops, looks like the page is lost. This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional

Tags: reactjs, http-status-code-404, admin, dashboard

I hosted my React JS Admin Dashboard on hostinger by default first time it is opening but when i click to refresh the page that time it is  showing error:

> Oops, looks like the page is lost.
> This is not a fault, just an accident that was not intentional.